# Эмуляция нажатий клавиш и автозаполнение полей в браузере

Tags: javascript, ооп

Задача: есть контент-менеджер, который заливает однотипные картинки на сайт и добавляет им одинаковые описания. Сайт чужой, доступа к нему нет.

Есть ли возможность написать программу, которая будет автоматически делать эти действия за него? Например, эмуляция нажатия на поле, потом ввод текста в поле, дальше выбор картинки из папки и нажатие кнопки отправки.

Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Какая платформа (Mac, Windows)? Под OS X есть хорошая штука [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488?viewlocale=ru_RU).

Может быть, проанализировать протокол и делать те же POST запросы из своего скрипта, однажды авторизовавшись на том сайте?

Есть расширения под браузеры, автоматизирующие работу с сайтами, напр. [GreaseMonkey](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), подойдёт?

Наконец, тяжёлая артиллерия - автоматизация браузера [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: iMacros - все делает элементарно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете посмотреть в сторону [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). 
При использовании поднимается браузер (firefox, chrome) и имитируется сценарий работы пользователя. Можно адекватно обходить формы с динамическими полями. Умеет делать скриншот всей страницы, что иногда может быть полезно.

Answer (score 0):

[Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - даже поднимать селениум не нужно (и тем более ждать работы реального браузера).

Кстати, selenium умеет работать с phantomjs, с которым всё тоже идет слегка побыстрее и в headless-режиме.